# PHP vs Python Framework

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, bottle

Sorry if this question is a little general.

I am developing a basic Raspberry Pi timer to turn things on an off (nothing new).

There seems to be two approach.

1. Use SQL and PHP to create a database and PHP to create the user interface. Then a basic Python script that polls the SQL database and acts on the timing events. Turning things off and on.
2. Use a modern Python framework like Bottle or Flask to provide the interface to a python script to connects to a database like SQLite or Redis.

My question is:

In option 2 can those frameworks be used to provide the same level of functionality as PHP for the database management. Record creation and deletion etc.

In option 1 is there a way to get live interaction with the Pi going. As in buttons that turn things on and off as well as provide live status back from the Python script showing values of various variables like temp values or GPIO values.

What route would you take if building something similar? Basic timing control and some temp logging.

Many thanks and sorry again for the generic overview.

T

Comment: I would go for option two. You can easily interact with the database.

Comment: Personally I would consider a node.js based solution due to the event driven / real-time nature of what you are trying to do - maybe have a look at the strongloop framework --> https://strongloop.com/